# Magic function to cast object to integer in php 7

Tags: php, object, casting, integer

I like to program object oriented so I want to make my own IntegerObject class. But when I try to execute the following code:

```
$x = new IntegerObject(3)
echo $x / 3;
```

I get the error:

> Object of class IntegerObject could not be converted to int

Is there a magic function like __toString() to cast an object to an integer?

Answer (score 1):

**Workaround**

As PHP is dynamically type casting language you can magically cast to string and the PHP will cast it to integer:

```
$x = new IntegerObject(3);
echo "$x" / 3;
```

Comment: It still issues the notice. Check http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/55d4b8870cb80ba2b4775cf3c1ee889b9cb98510

Comment: @AlexBlex If `$x` is surrounded with double quotes it dosn't: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f0bc8d1dd6c2695f2848b7f080478d9194586f2a

Comment: Ah, fair enough. Missed the quotes.

Answer (score 0):

You can cast to an integer using the `(int)` operator:

```
$x = new IntegerObject(3);
var_dump((int) "$x" / 3);
```

That should show you that the result is an int.